# Error while creating a new method for a new class in R

Tags: r

I got an error while creating a new method for a new class

> > setClass("CIR", representation(PATH="numeric", GRID="numeric", PARAMS="numeric"));
>   [1] "CIR"
>   >
>   > setMethod("plot", signature(x="CIR"), ,
>   +           function(x) {
>   + plot(slot(x,"GRID"),slot(x,"PATH"),type="l")
>   + points(slot(x,"GRID"),slot(x,"PATH"),col="red",cex=0.5)
>   +           })
>   Error in as.environment(where) : invalid object for 'as.environment'

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two commas at the end of the line containing `setMethod`, which means you inadvertently left `definition` blank and set `where` to a function.  Try this instead:

```
setMethod("plot", signature(x="CIR"),
  function(x) {
  plot(slot(x,"GRID"),slot(x,"PATH"),type="l")
  points(slot(x,"GRID"),slot(x,"PATH"),col="red",cex=0.5)
})
```