# How to custom print/show variables (with custom class) in my R package

Tags: r, methods, printing, console, r-package

Many R functions return objects that are printed to the console in a special manner. For instance, `t_results = t.test(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,4))` will assign a `list` to the `t_results` variable, but when I enter this variable in the console, or call it as `print(t_results)` or `show(t_results)`, it prints some plain text information (such as `Welch Two Sample t-test...` etc.) instead of returning the actual `list`. (This is a base R function, but I've seen this implemented in many custom user R packages just as well.)

My question is: how do I do this for objects created in my own custom R package? I've read several related questions and answers (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240939/in-r-how-can-i-set-a-generic-method-on-a-class-from-another-package), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638307/changing-how-output-is-printed-to-the-console/34638830#34638830), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230064/error-while-creating-a-new-method-for-a-new-class-in-r?rq=1)), which do give a general idea (using `setMethod` for my custom classes), but none of them makes it clear to me what exactly I need to do to make it work properly in a custom R package. I also cannot find any official documentation or tutorial on the matter.

To give an example of what I want to do, here is a very simple function from my hypothetical R package, which simply return a small `data.frame` (with an arbitrary class name I add to it, here `'my_df_class'`):

```r
my_main_function = function() {
    my_df = data.frame(a = c('x1', 'y2', 'z2'),
                       b = c('x2', 'y2', 'z2'))
    class(my_df) = c(class(my_df), 'my_df_class')
    return(my_df)
}
```

I would like to have this printed/shown e.g. like this:

```r
my_print_function = function(df) {
    cat('My results:', df$a[2], df$a[3])
}
# see my_print_function(my_main_function())
```

What exactly has to be done to make this work for my R package (i.e., that when someone installs my R package, assigns the `my_main_function()` results to a variable, and `print`s/`show`s that variable, it would be done via `my_print_function()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small explanation. Adding to the amazing answer posted by @nya:

First, you are dealing with S3 classes. With these classes, we can have one method manipulating the objects differently depending on the class the object belongs to.

Below is a simple class and how it operates:

1. Class contains numbers,
2. The class values to be printed like 1k, 2k, 100k, 1M,
3. The values can be manipulated numerically.

-- Lets call the class `my_numbers`

Now we will define the class constructor:

```
 my_numbers = function(x) structure(x, class = c('my_numbers', 'numeric'))
```

Note that we added the class 'numeric'. ie the class `my_numbers` INHERITS from numeric class

We can create an object of the said class as follows:

```
b <- my_numbers(c(100, 2000, 23455, 24567654, 2345323))
b 
[1]      100     2000    23455 24567654  2345323
attr(,"class")
[1] "my_numbers" "numeric"
```

Nothing special has happened. Only an attribute of class has been added to the vector. You can easily remove/strip off the attribute by calling `c(b)`

```
c(b)
[1]      100     2000    23455 24567654  2345323
```

vector `b` is just a normal vector of numbers.

Note that the `class` attribute could have been added by any of the following (any many more ways):

```
 class(b) <- c('my_numbers', 'numeric')
 attr(b, 'class') <- c('my_numbers', 'numeric')
 attributes(b) <- list(class = c('my_numbers', 'numeric'))
```

Where is the magic?

I will write a simple function with recursion. Don't worry about the function implementation. We will just use it as an example.

```
my_numbers_print = function(x, ..., digs=2,  d = 1,  L =   c('', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T')){
  ifelse(abs(x) >= 1000, Recall(x/1000, d = d + 1),
         sprintf(paste0('%.',digs,'f%s'), x, L[d]))
}

my_numbers_print(b)
[1] "100.00" "2.00K"  "23.45K" "24.57M" "2.35M"
```

There is no magic still. Thats the normal function called on `b`.

Instead of calling the function `my_numbers_print` we could write another function with the name `print.my_numbers` ie `method.class_name` (Note I added the parameter `quote = FALSE`

```
print.my_numbers = function(x, ..., quote = FALSE){
   print(my_numbers_print(x), quote = quote)
 }
   
 b
[1] 100.00 2.00K  23.45K 24.57M 2.35M
```

Now b has been printed nicely. We can still do math on b

```
 b^2
 [1] 10.00K  4.00M   550.14M 603.57T 5.50T
```

Can we add b to a dataframe?

```
data.frame(b)
         b
1      100
2     2000
3    23455
4 24567654
5  2345323
```

`b` reverts back to numeric instead of maintaining its class. That is because we need to change another function. ie the `formats` function.

Ideally, the correct way to do this is to create a format function and then the print function. (Becoming too long)

---

## Summary : Everything Put Together

```
# Create a my_numbers class definition function
my_numbers = function(x) structure(x, class = c('my_numbers', 'numeric'))

# format the numbers
format.my_numbers =  function(x,...,digs =1, d = 1,  L =   c('', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T')){
      ifelse(abs(x) >= 1000, Recall(x/1000, d = d + 1),
         sprintf(paste0('%.',digs,'f%s'), x, L[d]))
}

#printing the numbers
print.my_numbers = function(x, ...) print(format(x), quote = FALSE)

# ensure class is maintained after extraction to allow for sort/order etc
'[.my_numbers' = function(x, ..., drop = FALSE)  my_numbers(NextMethod('['))


b <- my_numbers(c(2000, 100, 20, 23455, 24567654, 2345323))

data.frame(x = sort(-b) / 2)                     
   
       x
1 -12.3M
2  -1.2M
3 -11.7K
4  -1.0K
5  -50.0
6  -10.0
```

Comment: To me printing (outside the package) only works if I export the `print.my_print_function` function (putting `#'@export` above it for roxygen). This also seems to mean that classes can still be lost if the package is not loaded. (I upvoted and plan to accept, but I'm still checking if everything works.)

Comment: @gaspar i dont know how you wrote your function, Note that foe example `print.data.tabla` is not exported. ie `data.table::print.data.table` function does not exist. but you can access it as it is in the internals of the package ie `data.table:::print.data.table` this exists

Comment: Ah okay but it's specified as [S3method(print, data.table)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/e9a323de01a17af70d5316016606fa8d35b25023/NAMESPACE#L68) (which in roxygen is indicated as `#'@export`)

Comment: @gaspar Yeah its an S3 method. I see what you mean. Thats fine. Do the one that makes your code work. I often think of the `export` as the ones which have been exported

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use a specific function for a class is to set it as an S3 generic.

```
print.my_df_class = function(df) {
    cat('My results:', df$a[2], df$a[3])
}
```

Note that because you retain the `data.frame` class on line `class(my_df) = c(class(my_df), 'my_df_class')`, the `print()` will show the printing of the data.frame.

```
print(my_main_function())
#    a  b
# 1 x1 x2
# 2 y2 y2
# 3 z2 z2
```

You can either use `print.my_df_class()`, or modify the `my_main_function()` class assignment.

```
my_main_function = function() {
    my_df = data.frame(a = c('x1', 'y2', 'z2'),
                       b = c('x2', 'y2', 'z2'))
    class(my_df) = 'my_df_class'
    return(my_df)
}
```

Then you can use `print` without the class specification at the end to get a class-specific response.

```
print(my_main_function())
# My results: y2 z2
```

Comment: I can just change the order to `class(my_df) = c("my_df_class", class(my_df))`. However, when I try `show(my_main_function())`, it gives an error: `Error in print.my_df_class(object, useS4 = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (useS4 = FALSE)`

Comment: The error can be solved by adding ellipsis to the function arguments `print.my_df_class = function(df, ...) {`.