# Transforming a 'Value' column with €67.5M character types to Integers in R

Tags: r

I now have a column with (eg €67.5M) character types that I would like to convert to integers (€67,000,000). I guess I am not phrasing my question appropriately in Google to attempt this myself or the question is just too broad for a general search. I also notice that `dput(fifa21_raw_data$Value)` shows text that I am unfamiliar with. Perhaps newline characters? If so I would like to remove those as well if possible as they appear to be in all three columns I would like to transform here:

```
dput(fifa21_raw_data$Wage[1:20])
c("�\u0082�560K", "�\u0082�220K", "�\u0082�125K", "�\u0082�370K", 
"�\u0082�270K", "�\u0082�240K", "�\u0082�160K", "�\u0082�160K", 
"�\u0082�250K", "�\u0082�250K", "�\u0082�210K", "�\u0082�260K", 
"�\u0082�310K", "�\u0082�250K", "�\u0082�125K", "�\u0082�350K", 
"�\u0082�300K", "�\u0082�300K", "�\u0082�190K", "�\u0082�145K")

dput(fifa21_raw_data$Value[1:20])
c("�\u0082�67.5M", "�\u0082�46M", "�\u0082�75M", "�\u0082�87M", 
"�\u0082�90M", "�\u0082�80M", "�\u0082�105.5M", "�\u0082�62.5M", 
"�\u0082�78M", "�\u0082�78M", "�\u0082�75.5M", "�\u0082�69.5M", 
"�\u0082�59.5M", "�\u0082�56M", "�\u0082�29M", "�\u0082�53M", 
"�\u0082�24.5M", "�\u0082�53M", "�\u0082�51M", "�\u0082�65M")

dput(fifa21_raw_data$`Release Clause`[1:20])
c("�\u0082�138.4M", "�\u0082�75.9M", "�\u0082�159.4M", "�\u0082�161M", 
"�\u0082�166.5M", "�\u0082�132M", "�\u0082�203.1M", "�\u0082�120.3M", 
"�\u0082�144.3M", "�\u0082�144.3M", "�\u0082�145.3M", "�\u0082�147.7M", 
"�\u0082�122M", "�\u0082�119M", "�\u0082�47.9M", "�\u0082�108.7M", 
"�\u0082�50.2M", "�\u0082�98.1M", "�\u0082�96.9M", "�\u0082�112.1M")
```

Thank you so much for your time and efforts!

This one is going to take a bit more than simple gsub calling I think. Above my skill level so I would appreciate maybe a little explanation to your process as well! Still trying to learn the ropes. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use substr() to spit your data into multiple columns, to make "u0082�560K" into two variables. Then substring to get the M or K alone in a column, and then filter on the M or K, substring from the right to get everything left of the M or K as a column, then multiply by 100,000 for the k subset, or 1,000,000 for the M subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
dct <- c(K = 'e3', M = 'e6', B = 'e9')
map_df(df, ~as.numeric(str_replace_all(str_remove(.x,"\\D+"), dct)))

# A tibble: 20 × 3
        x         y         z
    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 560000  67500000 138400000
 2 220000  46000000  75900000
 3 125000  75000000 159400000
 4 370000  87000000 161000000
 5 270000  90000000 166500000
 6 240000  80000000 132000000
 7 160000 105500000 203100000
 8 160000  62500000 120300000
 9 250000  78000000 144300000
10 250000  78000000 144300000
11 210000  75500000 145300000
12 260000  69500000 147700000
13 310000  59500000 122000000
14 250000  56000000 119000000
15 125000  29000000  47900000
16 350000  53000000 108700000
17 300000  24500000  50200000
18 300000  53000000  98100000
19 190000  51000000  96900000
20 145000  65000000 112100000
```

where

---

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("�\u0082�560K", "�\u0082�220K", 
"�\u0082�125K", "�\u0082�370K", "�\u0082�270K", "�\u0082�240K", 
"�\u0082�160K", "�\u0082�160K", "�\u0082�250K", "�\u0082�250K", 
"�\u0082�210K", "�\u0082�260K", "�\u0082�310K", "�\u0082�250K", 
"�\u0082�125K", "�\u0082�350K", "�\u0082�300K", "�\u0082�300K", 
"�\u0082�190K", "�\u0082�145K"), y = c("�\u0082�67.5M", 
"�\u0082�46M", "�\u0082�75M", "�\u0082�87M", "�\u0082�90M", 
"�\u0082�80M", "�\u0082�105.5M", "�\u0082�62.5M", 
"�\u0082�78M", "�\u0082�78M", "�\u0082�75.5M", "�\u0082�69.5M", 
"�\u0082�59.5M", "�\u0082�56M", "�\u0082�29M", "�\u0082�53M", 
"�\u0082�24.5M", "�\u0082�53M", "�\u0082�51M", "�\u0082�65M"
), z = c("�\u0082�138.4M", "�\u0082�75.9M", "�\u0082�159.4M", 
"�\u0082�161M", "�\u0082�166.5M", "�\u0082�132M", 
"�\u0082�203.1M", "�\u0082�120.3M", "�\u0082�144.3M", 
"�\u0082�144.3M", "�\u0082�145.3M", "�\u0082�147.7M", 
"�\u0082�122M", "�\u0082�119M", "�\u0082�47.9M", 
"�\u0082�108.7M", "�\u0082�50.2M", "�\u0082�98.1M", 
"�\u0082�96.9M", "�\u0082�112.1M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Note that you could still want to maintain the code having `M,B,K` but numeric. In that case, look at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72024788/how-to-custom-print-show-variables-with-custom-class-in-my-r-package/72025662#72025662) which will maintain the letters and still do some math on them

Comment: Doing it all in one fell swoop. Very nice. Thank you for this.

Comment: Would I be able to create a scatterplot for the tibble you created? Specifically, using wage and value?

Answer (score 1):

Using `parse_number` from readr to deal with decimal numbers, and `str_ends` to work out whether it is thousands or millions.  If you expect billions you will need to add another `ifelse` statment.

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)
ifelse(str_ends(a, 'K'), 1e3, 1)*ifelse(str_ends(a, 'M'), 1e6, 1)*parse_number(a)
```